# Is there a way to POST data into ALM- DNG platform through Rest API via oslc configuration?

Tags: post, alm, dng

I have a Doors Next Generation project on ALM platform from IBM.
I have managed to retrieve data through an API but cannot find a way to POST data.
Is there a way?